# CGI script create file with wrong permissions

Tags: apache, permissions, cgi

I'm using standard `routers2.cgi` to display MRTG graphs using `.rrd` data files in a linux server.

This `routers.cgi` file reads rrd data files and create MRTG graphs to display them from a web url.

This system is working fine. Only problem is the `.png` graphs creates with 600 permissions. But it needs 644 permission to display from the web page. So I had to change the permissions manually. How can I fix this, any suggestions?

url:

```
domain.com/cgi-bin/routers2.cgi
```

graphs located at:

```
domain.com/graphs/
```

apache2 config:

```
cgi bin: <path>/domain.com/cgi-bin
doc root: <path>/domain.com/public_html/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well finally I have fixed it.

It got fix by adding following code in top of the script. In my case a have added it just below the ##CONFIG#START# comment line in the routers2.cgi

umask(0033);